# best way skip facebook login page in android if it is already logged in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am login my android app using the Facebook login. Here i am checking the Access Token is null or not so that i can move to another activity after login. This is working fine. please help is there any better way to move another activity when the facebook is already logged in?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boringmain);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("email");

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {
            Profile.setCurrentProfile(profile1);
        }
    };

    profileTracker.startTracking();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                 AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(currentAccessToken);
        }
    };

     if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(boringmain.this, UserProfile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      } 
     else 
      { 
        Log.e("S","User not logged in "); 
       }

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getUserDetails(loginResult);

        };

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }
```

is there any better method do the above scenario? The usage of profile tracker and access token tracker is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Checking if user is logged in by calling

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
```

is good way. But in my opinion better place to check it is before opening Login Activity. You can call this code everywhere you want and if **AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()** is **null** then open Login Activity

in Login Activity you should go to another activity after success login here:

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
       //START NEW ACTIVITY AFTER CORRECT LOGIN HERE

      Intent intent = new Intent(boringmain.this, UserProfile.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    };

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    };
  });
```